# I've successfully specified my exit node to be US, but Spotify Webplayer still detects a different country. How can I fix this?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, exit-relays, node

I've configured Tor to always have a US exit node, but when I go to the URL for Spotify Web Player, it says Spotify has not been released in your country yet (Spotify is released in the US). I have validated that Tor is using a US exit node, and have run this many times with different paths (always with US exit).

How can I resolve?

Answer (score 1):

Quite a usual situation even with VPN. The reason can be one of three:

- **GeoIP fail** - There're a lot of IP-to-location databases, free and paid ones... And even the best ones and **even** combining the best ones can give you an artifacts like that: I used to win a one year free subscription to 4 databases by pointing my home static IP from Moscow to be identified as an Amsterdam by 3 DB's and other one supposed I was in Texas, US...
- **Poorly or intentionally configured website** - Some IP-to-geo DB's can identify some proxies and Tor exits as not a country, but a zone like A1,A0,etc.. So if the system does not know where you're from - it shows "Oops, you're not allowed" screen without being specific in details.
- **Tracking script issue** - Usually Tor will try to route different "streams" in different circuits, so you can hit this kind of situation either by hitting one of the first two cases by a tracking script "routing pipe", or just by a glitch. You can reproduce this situation by creating a page with a pack of different domains+IP's for a pack of tracking scripts and especially executing them from client side.

So just send a Tor "SIGNAL NEWNYM" over the control port and try again